# Autocorrelation function of random process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a  wide sense stationary random process indexed by $t\in\mathbb{R}$ with finite mean and variance.  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process)

Q1) Is the autocorrelation function of $X_t$ Lebesgue measurable?

Q2) Is the autocorrelation function of $X_t$ equivalent to a continuous function almost everywhere?

**update:**

measurability is actually equivalent to continuity a.e.

Comment: The power spectral density of a Gaussian white noise is a constant, so the autocorrelation function is a Dirac delta function. Hence the variance is not finite.

Comment: I see the confusion now. I should have been more precise. See the updated question.

Comment: Okay, I see. I'll remove my comments in a second